# BigQuery Standard SQL - Unable to use Alias

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My company has recently switched to big query, one issue I am having right now is that big query in standard SQL is not able to accept alias columns in query.

For eg. returns me `Unrecognized name: product_code at [3:5]`. 
Does anyone knows a workaround on this issue?

```
 select sales, t_001 as product_code
 from "project_01.sales_001.trans_datamart"
 where product_code = '001-40040-00'
```

Comment: Correct.  BigQuery -- like all other databases -- does not allow the use of a column alias in the `where` clause.  Use a CTE or subquery if you need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#where_clause), you can not reference an alias from the `SELECT` and list it in a `WHERE` clause. The where clause filters each row against a `bool_expression`.

However, there is a way for you to achieve what you want. Below is the syntax:

```
select sales, product_code
from (select *, t_001 as product_code from "project_01.sales_001.trans_datamart")
where product_code = '001-40040-00'
```

Therefore, you use the alias as a new column name within your `from` clause, which makes possible for you to filter using the alias you just created in your `where` clause.

I would also encourage you to check out this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#aliases) with all the explanations about aliases in BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of *any* SQL dialect that allows the use of a column alias in the `WHERE` clause.

Sticking to just the clauses in your example, SQL engines generally evaluate the `FROM` clause first, determining which tables to pull data from, then evaluate the `WHERE` clause to filter the retrieved data, and then the `SELECT` clause to determine what to display and how to display it.

Given that, the column alias is unknown to the SQL engine at the point that it's reading the `WHERE` clause.

So your options are to either use the column name in the `WHERE` clause, or, as Gordon suggests in the comments, put the alias in a sub-query or CTE that will be evaluated as part of the `FROM` clause.

Column name:

```
 select sales, t_001 as product_code
 from "project_01.sales_001.trans_datamart"
 where t_001 = '001-40040-00'               --<--- Modification here.
```

Sub-query:

```
select
  sales,
  product_code
from 
(
 select sales, t_001 as product_code
 from "project_01.sales_001.trans_datamart"
) as d
 where product_code = '001-40040-00'
```

Comment: Snowflake and Redshift allow it; off the top of my head - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/amazon-redshift-announces-support-for-lateral-column-alias-reference/